# When we click on a particular alphabet it should display relevant image..Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried using java script.. When I click on A alphabet I am unable to see the image. Iam very new to java script. Any help is appreciated.

```
    function iterateAlphabet(var index)
{
        var nextChar;
        var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            for(var index=0; index<str.length; index++)
            {
                nextChar = str.charAt(index);
                break;
            }
        return nextChar;
    }

    function getCharacter(var index)
        var  character = document.getElementById("alphabetA");
        character.innerText=iterateAlphabet(index);
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="image" src="imgs\\1.jpg" alt="a"  id="alphabetA"  onclick ="iterateAlphabet('0')" value="Apple"></input></td>
    </table>
```

Comment: What's this code meant to do?

Comment: First problem I see is that the src should probably be be `"imgs/1.jpg"`

Comment: That said, as David points out, this structure by itself doesn't make much sense, or why you would pass a number to the function to look up a letter, instead of simply passing "A" to it.

Comment: Will you have separated button for every letter on page? Or (i have that feel), you want to change all images/letters on click on same link?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you need but your codeis missing a `{` at `function getCharacter(var index)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

(function iterateAlphabet(){

```
 var alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split(''),
     imageUrl = "http://dummyimage.com/50x50/2e2e2e/fff&text=";

alpha.forEach( function(el){
  var link = document.createElement('A');
      link.href = imageUrl + el;
      link.innerHTML = el;

   // console.log(link); 

    document.write(link); // you can use any code here to show the links

 });
```

})()

Answer (score 0):

HTML structure (style it how you want, just keep id of elements, or change them in html and js, if you want):

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <td id="letters" onclick ="iterateAlphabet()">

        A
        </td>
        <td> <img src='A.jpg' id="alpha" ></td>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
i = 0;

function iterateAlphabet()
{
  var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  if (i < str.length)
  {
    i++;
    var nextChar = str.charAt(i);

document.getElementById("letters").innerHTML = nextChar;
    document.getElementById("alpha").src = nextChar + '.jpg';



    if (i == str.length - 1)
    {

      i = -1;

    }
  }

}
```

Most important: - you should have images named A.jpg, B.jpg, etc...etc... in same directory, and this will work.